# Average Previous and Current Row - Pandas

Tags: pandas

**OBJECTIVE**

- Calculate `avg_tot_assets`  where *avg_tot_assets = (prior year asset + current year assets)/2*
- Calculate `return_on_asset` (ROA) = `net income` / `avg_total_assets`

**APPROACH**

1. Use Quandl's API to pull in Boeing Financial Information
2. Create dataframe
3. Use Pandas to iterate through dataframe and calculate each year's average total assets
4. Use pandas to calculate ROA

**WORKING CODE**

```
df = data[['per_fisc_year',
           'consol_net_income_loss',
          'tot_asset',
          'curr_portion_debt',
          'tot_lterm_debt',
           'tot_share_holder_equity']]
df
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: dataframe]

**QUESTIONS**

1. I imagine looping through the dataframe isn't the most efficient/elegant way. I've looked into use groupby or index, but am unsure how to execute.
2. Similarly, if I were to calculate ROA - can I calculate `return_on_asset` in parallel while calculating `avg_tot_asset`, or would these have to be run independently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first question take a look at [Pandas Window Functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html). That will handle your `avg_tot_assets` with:

```
df['avg_tot_assets'] = df.tot_asset.rolling(window=2).mean()
```

As far as computing another column in parallel, there may be a way but you are unlikely to gain any performance by doing so. You are going to be better of doing it sequentially. Like so:

```
df['ROA'] = df.net_income / df.avg_tot_assets
```

You could try to waste a bunch of time writing a complicated function that will go through the dataframe row-wise and calculate each value in turn then applying the output to the original dataframe, but this will be **DRASTICALLY** slower than the built in methods.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to a windowing function, you could use `shift` to get the previous value of a column:

```
df['avg_tot_assets'] = df['tot_asset'].add(df['tot_asset'].shift(1)) / 2
```

and nothing new for the ROA calculation. I imagine pandas/numpy can vectorise that calculation:

```
df['ROA'] = df['consol_net_income_loss'] / df['avg_tot_assets']
```